# Angular string interpolation prints empty string on JSON object value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-template

In my typescript class:

```
user = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    secret: '',
    gender: '',
    answer: '',
};
```

i have a button called onSubmit:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.form);
    this.user.username = this.form.value.userData.username;
    console.log(this.user.username);
}
```

and in my HTML:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="submitted">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>Your Data</h3>
        <p>Username: {{ user.username }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The console log clearly prints the value of the user.username and I can see it in the console. But the html just shows:

Your Data

Username:

Comment: To edit: the onSubmit is somewhere in my HTML and it works fine because i can see the console output.

Comment: What is the changeDetection strategy on the component?

Comment: @OneLunchMan Can you elaborate on the question?

Comment: @OneLunchMan https://pastebin.com/1nSHRCPb that is the HTML code

Comment: The typescript is what I am looking for. 
Also, read up on this https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: @OneLunchMan https://pastebin.com/haBmfEKw thats the typescript

Comment: @OneLunchMan i think there is two ways to forms: reactive and template. I'm using the latter.

Comment: I don't think the issue is forms, I think it's that the changeDetection cycle either did not run or did not pick up there was a valid change. Try wiring in the ChangeDetectorRef and call detectChanges

Comment: Please show entire component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code https://pastebin.com/1nSHRCPb

The issue had happened because of line 18

```
    ...
    #user="ngModel">
```

You've created a template variable `user`. That's why you get nothing when called `user.username` in your template.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue. This was really nasty to spot. What made it worse was that I was following along with the tutorial.

Comment: You've just looked through tired eyes. That happens. Glad, that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The prior reply will solve your issue. I did a stackblitz of it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hirffj

But you may be able to simplify your code even further if you use two-way binding.

```
        <input
         type="text" 
         id="username" 
         class="form-control"
         [(ngModel)]="user.username"
         name="username"
         required>
```

Then your input element and your `user.username` property will stay in sync.

Also note that the `setValue` and `patchValue` shown in your component code is for `reactive forms`, not `template driven forms`. Since you are using `template driven forms`, if you change to use two-way binding you can set the values into the form just using the object properties:

```
  suggestUserName() {
    this.user.username = 'Superuser';
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, much appreciated!

Comment: I have a more complete example using two-way binding here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-forms-deborahk Hope it is helpful.